# Apply different Decorator to different folder based on folder name

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Is it possible to apply different decorator to different folder based on folder name.

I have developed a plugin which creates a custom project, with 4 folders.
I want that, for each time new project is created each folder must have different icon.

**Is it possible to do it through decorator? If not, then please let me know of other way around.**

---

Currently, I am applying decorator in following way.
But in this case the same icon is applied to all the folders, which I don't want.

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
      <decorator
            adaptable="true"
            icon="img/folder-script.png"
            id="abcd.main.ui.decorator.folder.script"
            label="Script Folder Decorator"
            lightweight="true"
            location="TOP_LEFT"
            state="true"> 
            <enablement>
                 <objectClass
                       name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
                 </objectClass>
            </enablement>
      </decorator>
   </extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `objectState` as part of the `enablement` to test the name:

```xml
<enablement>
   <and> 
      <objectClass
          name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
      </objectClass>
      <objectState
          name="name"
          value="the folder name">
      </objectState>
   </and>
</enablement>
```